# Easy way to change specific list item in list

Tags: clojure

In Clojure I want change specific item(list) in list with other.
Here is my structure:

```
(def myLis '((3 3) (5 5) (5 5)))
(def som '(4 4))
```

I want change second element in `myLis` with `som`.
Result in `myLis` is `'((3 3) (4 4) (5 5))`
This is basic example. I have few hundred items in myList.
I try assoc and update-in but this not work on list.

When I try with assoc and update:

```
(update-in myLis [1] som)
(assoc myLis 1 som)
(assoc-in myLis [1] som)
```

got error like that:

```
clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Associative
```

How can quick change nth element in this structure (list of lists).

Comment: Why are you using a list if you need to be able to change items at specific indices?

Comment: @SamEstep Because this structure is good for me in some point of code.

Comment: @Nejc    I hope you find the below answer usefule.

Comment: @AlanThompson Yes thank you for answer It's work. I write my basic solution (see below the question), where I keep list structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an additional answer using loop/recur to realign the OP's own solution to be more lisp like.

```
(defn list-update-in-recur [l i x]
  (loop [new-data [] old-list l]
    (if (seq old-list)
      (if (= (count new-data) i)
        (recur (conj new-data x) (rest old-list))
        (recur (conj new-data (first old-list)) (rest old-list)))
      (apply list new-data))))

user> (list-update-in-recur '((1 2) (2 3) (3 4)) 1 '(8 9))
((1 2) (8 9) (3 4))
```

A few points to note:

1. It's written as a function, there are no 'def' values to set any global value. The final result is the return of the function `(apply list new-data)`
2. Arguments initialise the loop, the size of the growing list is used to determine if we want to replace the nth item or not (no index variables)
3. The passed in list becomes the initial `old-list` value which reduces in size each iteration, and the exit condition is simply if there are any more elements left in it using the test `(seq old-list)`, which returns false/nil when it is empty.
4. <s>Because we `conj` everything (which adds to start of the list) we reverse it to return the output.</s> It now uses a vector to create the new sequence, and converts to a list as the last step instead of reversing a list
5. I've replaced `nth` with `first` and `rest` which are more efficient and don't have to traverse entire lists every iteration.
6. This is still very inefficient and only provided as a learning exercise.

Comment: Thank you. This example is much easier to understanding. I try `reverse`, but take much time. Here is reason, why I use syntax like this: `(def newL (conj newL som))`

Comment: I've update the version to not need the reverse. Internally it uses a `vector` (where conj adds to the end) instead of `list` (which adds to the start), and then instead of reversing it, instead converts from final vector to a list. As has been said elsewhere, you should be able to work with a vector in your other code as easily as a list if you think of sequences instead of hard lists. What is it you ultimately want to do with the changed list?

Comment: Only reason is, because all my functions works with lists. For next project I use vector for sure.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the clojure bible ([Clojure Programming](http://www.clojurebook.com/)):

> Because [lists] are linked lists, they do not support efficient random
>   access; thus, nth on a list will run in linear time (as opposed to
>   constant time when used with vectors, arrays, and so on), and get does
>   not support lists at all because doing so would not align with get’s
>   objective of sublinear efficiency.

So in order to replace an element of a list you will have to traverse all the elements up to it, thus running longer the further your item is in the list, and rebuild the list with the elements before it, the new item and all the elements after it (rest). Alternatively, turn the list into a vector, use update-in and back into a list if you absolutely have to use lists.

However, if you can, it would be worth seeing if you can use sequences in your code rather than lists, and thus you can interchangeably use vectors or other abstractions that are more efficient for the processing you are performing over them.

A trivial function that would meet the basics of your requirement with lists however, is:

```
(defn list-update-in [l i x]
  (let [newlist (take i l)
        newlist (concat newlist (list x))
        newlist (concat newlist (drop (+ 1 i) l))]
    newlist))

user> (list-update-in '((1 2) (2 3) (3 4)) 1 '(8 9))
((1 2) (8 9) (3 4))
```

There's no out of bounds checks on this

Comment: thanks Alan, I dusted off a copy of Little Schema and was going to write a very lispy way of doing this when it struck me I could just use take and drop.

Answer (score 2):

You should normally use vectors like `[1 2 3]` in preference to lists like `'(1 2 3)` for most purposes.  In Clojure, a list is normally used for a function call like `(+ 1 2)`, while for data literals vectors normally used like `[1 2 3]`.

Here is code showing 2 options that work.

Main code:

```
(ns clj.core
  (:require 
    [tupelo.core :as t]
  ))
(t/refer-tupelo)

(def myLis [ [3 3] [5 5] [5 5] ] )
(def som [4 4] )

(spyx (assoc      myLis  1  som))
(spyx (assoc-in   myLis [1] som))

(defn -main [& args]
  (println "-main"))
```

Result:

```
~/clj > lein run    
(assoc myLis 1 som)      => [[3 3] [4 4] [5 5]]
(assoc-in myLis [1] som) => [[3 3] [4 4] [5 5]]
```

You need this in `project.clj` to make the `(spy ...)` work:

```
:dependencies [
  [tupelo "0.9.9"] 
  ...
```

### Update 2016-11-2:

If you really want to keep everything in a list, you can use `replace-at` [from the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#replacing-values-in-a-sequence).  It works like this:

```
(def myLis '( (3 3) (5 5) (5 5) ) )
(def vec-1    [4 4] )
(def list-1  '(4 4) )

(spyx             (t/replace-at myLis 1 vec-1 ))
(spyx             (t/replace-at myLis 1 list-1))
(spyx (apply list (t/replace-at myLis 1 list-1)))
```

with result

```
> lein run
(t/replace-at myLis 1 vec-1)               => [(3 3) [4 4] (5 5)]
(t/replace-at myLis 1 list-1)              => [(3 3) (4 4) (5 5)]
(apply list (t/replace-at myLis 1 list-1)) => ((3 3) (4 4) (5 5))
```

The first 2 examples show that the new element can be anything, such as the vector `[4 4]` or the list `(4 4)`.  Also, notice that `replace-at` always returns a vector result.  If you want the final result to be a list as well, you need to use `(apply list <some-collection>)`.

Comment: I know vectors is better solution, but in my case in program I using lists and I want work on list in this case.

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted. He's right, you should use vectors and just saying "i want to work on lists" is not a valid reason.

Comment: I have seen that some troll will often downvote answers that are not deemed "pure enough".   Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

**My solution with lists:**

```
(def newL '())
(def i 1)
(loop [k (- (count myLis) 1)]
  (when (> k -1)
    (cond
      (= k i) (def newL (conj newL som))
      :else (def newL (conj newL (nth myLis k)))
    )
    (recur (- k 1))
  )
)
```

Comment: are you learning clojure and lisp together? your solution helps you understand how loop/recur work, but you should also think about using HOF (Higher Order Functions) like take/drop/reduce/map as you will see these much more commonly in clojure code. Also, your syntax is very java like (closing brackets on separate lines), try to get used to putting closing them together instead. Additionally, learn to use let, you almost never should use `def` inside functions, they are generally top level forms. Your code suggests you're trying to translate java directly into clojure.

Comment: Additionally, your algorithm is very inefficient. You're always looping the entire length of your list and `conj`ing every item onto the end of a new list, which will get slower as your list size increases. Also, `nth` has to traverse the entire list every time too, to get the item you're after, so you're traversing over the list multiple times, each time over a longer list. Look at `take` and `drop` and think how it would be quicker to use these without any looping. Your code also suggests you're not thinking functionally, and using `newL` as a variable, which again isn't how lisps work.

Comment: @MarkFisher Great explanation and good overview of my mistakes. I only few times writing in functional languages and have problems with that. I make some basic examples in Lisp. In this point I put together knowledge from lisp and object-oriented programming languages. I agree with you, my code is a complete confusion.